# How do I create a SQL server so I can connect to server management

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

The title might be a little confusing so I am going to explain my problem in detail so please read all of this before you all go quickly shut down this question for being a copy.

I got two problems, one is that I don't know how to make a server for Microsoft SQL SMS. As in when I start it up I have no idea what to type into the connection thing because when I try to do a simple localhost for server name it gives me an error. All the tutorials online act like I should already know what to do up to that point so skip over it without explaining how to set up a server.

Now I know it is a server ***management*** tool for databases, but I received a .bak file from my supervisor that contains all the data outlines and all that good stuff.

So pretty much I want to know how to take this .bak file and somehow create a server or something so I can use this data. If this is unclear I am more than willing to expand upon this. I realize my question was not as clear and people quickly shut it down claiming it was the same as other questions.

Comment: Any help would be great, it is a rather simple question

Comment: It's not simple at all.  You need to install and configure a SQL Server instance.  The fact that you don't know this means you have a lot of reading to do.

Comment: What exactly did you install? Just the client tools or a server as well? If you are on Express the default instance name is probably `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install an instance of SQL Server (it's not clear to me that you have done that). You can use the free [SQL Server Expres Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx) *unless*:

- the data file(s) consume more than 10GB
- the database uses features that require a higher SKU (Standard/Enterprise)

We have no idea whether either of those conditions are true. If they are, then you can buy the [Developer Edition for about $50](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007RFXQAM) (feel free to shop around), assuming you are not planning to install this on a server and use it in production.

I am suggesting SQL Server 2012 only because it is the latest supported release. You can choose to use SQL Server 2008 or any other version, but your best chance at compatibility with this backup file you've been given is if you are restoring it to a version that is *later* or equal to the version where it was backed up.

This site is not the place for step-by-step instructions on installing an instance of SQL Server ([you can find those elsewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)). Once you have an instance of SQL Server installed, then you need to find out what your database looks like. Usually your backup file will be created on a server where the database itself was installed in physical folders that do not match your own machine. So I suggest either finding out the default path by inspecting the output of this query (which tells you where the `master` data file is located):

```
SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files
  WHERE database_id = 1 AND [file_id] = 1;
```

Or creating a very simple folder called `c:\databases\`, giving the `Everyone` account modify privileges.

Then run the following (below I've assumed the backup is in c:\databases\ and that's where you want the data files; if that differs, adjust accordingly):

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'c:\databases\whatever.bak';
```

This will return a resultset like:

```
LogicalName    PhysicalName
-------------  ------------
Whatever       C:\...\whatever.mdf
Whatever_log   C:\...\whatever_log.ldf
```

You need to build a `RESTORE DATABASE` command something like the following, based on the result above:

```
RESTORE DATABASE foo FROM DISK = 'c:\databases\whatever.bak'
  WITH MOVE 'Whatever'     TO 'c:\databses\whatever.mdf',
       MOVE 'Whatever_log' TO 'c:\databases\whatever_log.ldf';
```

Now you can connect to the database using Management Studio. The server name you specify in the connection dialog will depend on what edition of SQL Server you installed, and whether you used a named instance or a default instance. You can tell whether it is a named instance or not by looking in the Services applet (Control Panel > Administrative Tools). There you should see at least one instance of `SQL Server`, and it will be followed either by `(MSSQLServer)` or `(InstanceNameYouChose)`. Here I have three named instances of SQL Server (the named instances are SQL2005, SQL2008, and SQL2012):

[image]

If you have a named instance, then you would connect in Management Studio using:

```
.\InstanceNameYouChose
```

So for example, to connect to my SQL2008 instance, I would say:

```
.\SQL2008
or
ServerName\SQL2008
or
(local)\SQL2008
or
LOCALHOST\SQL2008
or
127.0.0.1\SQL2008
etc. etc.
```

If you have a default instance then you don't need the slash and the subsequent name, it would just be:

```
.
or
ServerName
or
(local)
or
LOCALHOST
or
127.0.0.1
etc. etc.
```